# Check if table has a companyID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, ssms

Using SQl how would I check a column of all the tables in @DestinationDatabase if they have a CompanyID using an if statement? within the while loop of the code below?.

I have been told cursors have performance issues but this is the route that somebody above me has chosen to take.

```
DECLARE @firstLoop BIT
SET @firstLoop = true
DECLARE @Counter INT  -- counting variable

----------- Cursor specific code starts here ------------
-- company cursor
declare copyCompanyDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
SELECT ID from #CompanyIDs;

open copyCompanyDataCursor
fetch next from copyCompanyDataCursor into @Company_Id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        declare @processorder int;
        declare @tablename varchar(500);
        -- table cursor

        declare copyTableDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
        SELECT processorder,tablename from #TableList4 order by processorder;

        open copyTableDataCursor
        fetch next from copyTableDataCursor into @processorder, @tablename;

        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany] OFF

            -- Does the table have a companyID column? if statement checking for company id





            -- if yes then copy data based on companyID in cursor
            ELSE
              IF @firstLoop > =1 THEN

            -- if no check if this is the first time through company loop and copy all data
            -- if @firstloop company exists look at information schema

                    -- insert into c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany(selec
                    EXEC('INSERT ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ')')

                    -- company logic


            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany] ON

            FETCH NEXT FROM copyTableDataCursor into @processorder,@tablename;
        END

        close copyTableDataCursor;
        Deallocate copyTableDataCursor;

--INSERT INTO c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany
--SELECT *
--FROM production2.tCompany
--WHERE ISNULL(CompanyID, 0) = 0  -- copy all data where id is equal to zero
--@Destination_Database_Name

--      
        --EXEC(INSERT  + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + @Company_Id + ')'      
        SET @firstLoop = false;
        FETCH NEXT FROM copyCompanyDataCursor into @Company_Id;
    END
CLOSE copyCompanyDataCursor;
DEALLOCATE copyCompanyDataCursor;
```

Comment: You didn't post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your WHILE loop. I think this is the solution you're looking for.

```
IF (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.tables st
    INNER JOIN sys.columns sc
        ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
    WHERE st.NAME = @tablename
        AND sc.NAME = @company_id
    ) > 0
    BEGIN
        -- your logic here --
    END
ELSE
    -- other logic here --
```

Comment: Thanks any idea how I check if this is the first time the loop has ran

Comment: @madzcoding You can use print statements in my statement, with a variable counter.

Comment: @madzcoding Or do you intend to modify the flow of the program based on the first execution?